# Trying to understand one-class SVM

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to use one-class SVM with Python scikit-learn.
But I do not understand what are the different variables `X_outliers`, `n_error_train`, `n_error_test`, `n_error_outliers`, etc. which are at this [address](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html). Why does `X` is randomly selected and is not a part of a dataset?

Scikit-learn "documentation" did not help me a lot. Also, I found very few examples on Internet

Can I use One-class SVM for outlier detection in a case of a hudge number of data and if I do not know if there are anomalies in my training set?

> One-class SVM is an Unsupervised Outlier Detection ([here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html))
>
> One-class SVM is not an outlier-detection method, but a
> novelty-detection method ([here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html))

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not an expert on outlier-detection, but it might be worth a shot. What kind of data are you trying to classify? The one hint I can give is that very high dimensionality data (many columns / features) often doesn't work too well; Try to get your classification working with as few 'columns' as possible.

Comment: I want to classify data from boats, like their direction, their speed, etc. But after seeing those responses, I will try with the isolation forest algorithm, that is said efficient by scikit-learn

Answer (score 9):

Ok, so this is not really a Python question, more of a SVM comprehension question, but eh. A typical SVM is two-classed, and is an algorithm which is going to have two phases :

First, it will **learn** relationships between variables and attributes. For example, you show your algorithm tomato pictures and banana pictures, telling him each time if it's a banana or a tomato, and you tell him to count the number of red pixels in each picture. If you do it correctly, the SVM will be **trained**, meaning he will know that pictures with lots of red pixels are more likely to be tomatoes than bananas.

Then comes the **predicting** phase. You show him a picture of a tomato or a banana without telling him which it is. And since he has been trained before, he will count the red pixels, and know which it is.

In your case of a one-class SVM, it's a bit simpler, basically the training phase is showing him a bunch of variables which are all supposed to be similar. You show him a bunch of tomato pictures telling him "these are tomatoes, everything else too different from these are not tomatoes".

The code you link to is a code to test the SVM's capability of learning. You start by creating variables `X_train`. Then you generate two other sets, `X_test` which is similar to `X_train` (tomato pictures) and `X_outliers` which is very different. (banana pictures)

Then you show him the `X_train` variables and tell your SVM "this is the kind of variables we're looking for" with the line `clf.fit(X_train)`. This is equivalent in my example to showing him lots of tomato images, and the SVN learning what a "tomato" is.

And then you test your SVM's capability to sort new variables, by showing him your two other sets (`X_test` and `X_outliers`), and asking him whether he thinks they are similar to `X_train` or not. You ask him that with the `predict` fuction, and predict will yield for every element in the sets either "1" i.e. "yes this is a similar element to `X_train`", or "-1", i.e. "this element is very different".

In an ideal case, the SVM should yield only "1" for `X_test` and only "-1" for `X_outliers`. But this code is to show you that this is not always the case. The variables `n_error_` are here to count the mistakes that the SVM makes, misclassifying `X_test` elements as "not similar to `X_train` and `X_outliers` elements as "similar to `X_train`". You can see that there are even errors when the SVM is asked to predict on the very set that is has been trained on ! (`n_error_train`)

Why are there such errors ? Welcome to machine learning. The main difficulty of SVMs is setting the training set such that it enables the SVM to learn efficiently to distinguish between classes. So you need to set carefully the number of images you show him, (and what he has to look out for in the images (in my example, it was the number of red pixels, in the code, it is the value of the variable), but that is a different question).

In the code, the bounded but random initialization of the `X` sets means that for example you could during on run train the SVM on an `X_train` set with lots of values between -0.3 and 0 even though they are randomly initialized between -0.3 and 0.3 (espcecially if you have few elements per set, say for example 5, and you get [-0.2 -0.1 0 -0.1 0.1]). And so, when you show the SVM an element with a value of 0.2, then he will have trouble associating it to `X_train`, because it will have learned that `X_train` elements are more likely to have negative values.
This is equivalent to show your SVM a few yellow-ish tomatoes when you train him, so when you show him a really red tomato afterwards, it will have trouble clasifying it as a tomato.

Answer (score 1):

This one-class SVM is a classifier to determine whether entries are similar or dissimilar to entries that the classifier has been trained with.

The script generates three sets:

1. A training set.
2. A test-set of entries that are similar to the training a set.
3. A test-set of entries that are dissimilar to the training set.

The error is the number of entries from each of the sets, that have been classified wrongly. That is; That have been classified as dissimilar to the training set when they were similar (for set 1 and 2), or that have been classifier as similar to the training set when they were dissimilar (set 3).

- X_outliers: This is set 3.
- n_error_train: The number of classification errors for the elements in the train-set (1).
- n_error_test: The number of classification errors for the elements in the test-set (2).
- n_error_outliers: The number of classification errors for the elements in the outlier-set (3).

Answer (score 1):

This answer should be complementary to scikit-description but I agree that is a bit technical. I will elaborate some aspects of the One Class SVM algorithm (OCSVM) here. OCSVM is designed to solve the **unsupervised anomaly detection** problem.
Given unstructured (unlabelled) data  it will find a n-dimensional  space a matrix W^T with d columns (T stands for transpose).

The objective function of all SVM based methods (and OCSVM) is:
$$f(x) = sign(wT x + b)$$, where sign means sign (-1 anomalous 1 nominal) shifted by a bias  term b.

In the classification problem the matrix W is associated with the distance(margin) between 2 classes but this differs in OCSVM since there is only 1 class and it maximizes from the origin (original paper of OCSVM demonstrates [this](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1999/file/8725fb777f25776ffa9076e44fcfd776-Paper.pdf) ) .

As you see it is a generic algorithm because SVM is a family of models that can approximate any non linear boundary such as neural networks. To achieve something complicated you have to construct your own kernel matrix.

To do this you need to find some convenient mathematical property (suggestions to improve the answer are welcome at this point).
But in the most cases Gaussian kernel is a kernel that has some quite nice mathematical properties and associated ML theorems such as the [Large
of large numbers](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/other/law-of-large-numbers/#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%20and%20probability%20theory,a%20large%20number%20of%20times.&text=The%20result%20becomes%20closer%20to,an%20important%20concept%20in%20statistics).

The scikit implementation provides a wrapper to LIBSVM implementation for SVM and has 4 such kernels.

-nu parameter is a problem formulation parameter it allows to say to the model here is how dirty my sample is.
More formally it makes the problem a outlier detection problem where you know your data is mixed (nominal and anomalous) instead of pure where the problem is different and it is called [novelty detection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html).

- kernel parameter: One of the most important decisions. Mathematically kernel is a big matrix of numbers where by multiplying you achieve to project data in a higher dimensions. A nice read demonstrating the issue is [here](http://rvlasveld.github.io/blog/2013/07/12/introduction-to-one-class-support-vector-machines/) while the [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1999/file/8725fb777f25776ffa9076e44fcfd776-Paper.pdf) of Scholkopf who created OCSVMK goes into more detail.
- gamma
  In the case of robust kernel you essentially use a gaussian projection.
  Disclaimer my interpretation: Essentially with gamma parameter you describe how big the variance of the Normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma)$ is.

-tolerance
One class svm search the margin tha separates better among training data and the origin. The tolerance refers to the stopping criterion or how small should the tolerance for satisfaction of the quadratic optimization of the
objective function. The objective function the thing that tells SVM what the parameters should like to describe a specific margin - the space between nominal and anomalous) seen in Figure~([image: Novelty detection demonstrateion source, scikit-learn .]).